# Imprecision in floating point numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, nsnumber

If I create an `NSNumber` with a double value of `0.085`, it seems extra precision gets added to the number. However, this isn't the case with `0.85`. I don't understand why this is the case, but I'm sure there's a really obvious answer. Does anyone know why?

For example:

```
NSNumber *n1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.85];
NSNumber *n2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.085];

NSLog(@"Number: %@", n1);     // Number: 0.85
NSLog(@"Number: %@", n2);     // Number: 0.08500000000000001
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @HotLicks There is nothing wrong with this question and there is no requirement that someone has to know the entirety of a language before posting a question.

Comment: @AirsourceLtd - Maybe not, but he should have checked one of the 20 or so dupes that the "Ask Question" page presented him when he typed in his question.

Comment: @HotLicks - sure, but flag that then, not the OP's lack of knowledge.

Comment: @AirsourceLtd - Someone who does not have a working knowledge of C should not be using Objective-C (at least not with any serious intent).

Comment: Incidentally, the dupe I reported above is the first dupe that "Ask Question" presents when you type in the original title.

Comment: @AirsourceLtd a down vote seems a tad harsh - surely marking as a duplicate is sufficient. Bear in mind that the title of my question has been changed by another user so I wouldn't have seen the same suggestions by SO when entering the question. In any case, you clearly know more about C so I'll take this on board and brush up in this area. Thanks.

Comment: @Ian - I think you're talking to HotLicks. I didn't down vote you.

Comment: @AirsourceLtd, sorry, yes I meant to direct that to HotLicks. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I looked up the **original title** and typed that into Ask Question.  The above dupe is the first entry in the list that was presented.  A downvote is for "This question **does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or **not useful**."  Given that your question appears several times a week here, having it appear one more time is clearly "not useful", even if you had done some research (which you clearly didn't).

Comment: @HotLicks fair enough, you're entitled to your own opinion.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to `double` rather than `NSNumber`. `double` is a [floating-point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) value, and it does not provide precise decimal point numbers at specific level *by design*.